# Refering to another layer with Field Calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, within

Is there a way to select an attribute from a polygon layer and insert the value into a Virtual field of a point layer using `"within"` in the Field Calculator?

```sql
CASE
    WHEN within($geometry, geometry_polygon) THEN attribute_polygon
END
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use the 'Point sampling tool' plugin for this?

Comment: Because I need dynamic updates when creating new points or moving existing points.

Comment: You would be better off scripting this interaction rather than relying on out of the box tools.

Comment: Unfrotunately I don't have any scripting experience.

Comment: @LunarSea I've written an example below for you to follow, but you may have to tweak it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### For QGIS versions QGIS 3.16 and higher

Since QGIS 3.16 the functionality of the "refFunctions plugin" [was emended into core](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core). The current corresponding function is the [`overlay_within()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-within).

### For QGIS versions lower than QGIS 3.16

Spatial joins are available in the Field Calculator after installing the ["refFunctions" plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/).

```
geomwithin(targetLayer, targetField)
```

Keep in mind that:

> This plugin is deprecated!

Comment: Plug-ins are much simpler than using a custom script. Thanks!

Comment: geomwithin('targetLayer','targetField').

Answer (score 23):

Out of the box, field calculator does not support spatial joins across feature layers.  But, if you have a look at NathanW's post on the [function editor for qgis expressions](http://nathanw.net/2015/01/19/function-editor-for-qgis-expressions/) you will be able to make out that we can script our own data interaction.

The following script will allow you to express what you're after.  It works by iterating through all features on the polygon layer and if there is a spatial join, then reference tabular data from the specified column:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

allfeatures = None
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
indexMade = 0
refLayer = None

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def spatialJoinLookup(layerName, refColumn, defaultValue, geom, feature, parent):

    if geom is None:
        return defaultValue

    # globals so we don't create the index, refLayer more than once
    global allfeatures
    global index
    global indexMade
    global refLayer

    # Get the reference layer
    if refLayer is None:
        for layer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
            if layerName == layer.name():
                refLayer = layer
                break
    if refLayer is None:
        raise Exception("Layer [" + layerName + "] not found")

    # Create the index if not exists
    if indexMade == 0:
        index = QgsSpatialIndex()
        allAttrs = layer.pendingAllAttributesList()
        layer.select(allAttrs)
        allfeatures = {feature.id(): feature for (feature) in refLayer.getFeatures()}
        for f in allfeatures.values():
            index.insertFeature(f)
        indexMade = 1

    # Use spatail index to find intersect 
    fid = None
    ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
    for id in ids:
        fid = id
        break # Only get the first match.
    if fid is not None:
        return allfeatures[fid].attribute(refColumn)

    # Default
    return defaultValue
```

### Polygon Layer Example

Below is an example of a polygon layer that you might have. I've also created a corresponding point layer that you will see in the final image.

[image]

### Expression Usage

Note, if you want to use a separate column you must change the second argument to match the column name in the polygon dataset.  Example, you could use the 'AreaNumber' column, but would have to match the column type in the field calculator settings.

[image]

### Result

You can see that the default column value has been applied where there is no spatial join, and the other's have matched the correct data.  Note the script I've given will only join on the *first* match.  You would need to create some other business logic if your polygons were overlapping.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, your script is working fine using 'geom' instead of 'geometry' in the first 'if' statement. Joining geometries this way may be quite useful e.g. for creating multiple labels on polygons.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I missed that.  Hopefully there's no performance issues - I only tried it with a very small subset of records.

Comment: Having only 100+ point features QGIS struggles with performance issues. Adding a new point feature is really a pain even there is no point feature displayed in the acutal canvas. Otherwise when zooming in QGIS speeds up. I've tried `CASE WHEN $scale < 10000 THEN spatialJoinLookupI('Polygons', 'AreaName', 'None', $geometry) END' but it's not working. Is there anything I can do to improve the performance?

Comment: @LunarSea I've updated the function to use a spatial index.  It should be reasonably faster.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The spatial join is much faster now but unfortunaetely something isn't working properly. I'm getting differnt results for points within one and the same polygon.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue could be.  You could try following Nathan W's post http://nathanw.net/2013/01/04/using-a-qgis-spatial-index-to-speed-up-your-code/.  Could be that you have some residual intersections and may need to do another loop to filter them out.

Comment: I've created a new PostGIS table containing four polygon features. Intersection only works for one of the polygon features. Please take a look at the attached screenshot. I will need some Python knowledge to understand this.

Comment: Hi, the script works GREAT to use on a pointshape which is within a polygon shape. Is there a way to tweak it so it also works for polygons within polygons? When I run it for this sake I get a lot of false matches. refFunctions does work for polygon within polygon but takes ages to do what your script does in 10 seconds. Impressive!

Answer (score 22):

It can be done in **Field Calculator** with function `aggregate()`. In point layer create new field with field calculator expression like this:

```
aggregate(
layer:= 'polygon_layer_name',
aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:=joining_field_name,
concatenator:=', ',
filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```

Where `layer` is polygon layer name written like string, `aggreagate` is aggregate function (can be used also sum etc.), `expression` is field from values will be taken,`concatenator` is joining character string (have to be set, even in this case) and `filter` is filtering features based on expression (in this case interesects layer geometry with geometry of parent layer).

For more info check [Aggregates QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#aggregates-functions).

For automatic updates can be used *virtual fields* or you can set the expression as *Default value* in *Attributes Form* settings in *Layer Properties* ([Attribute form setting documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=default%20value#default-values)).

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that spatial functions (with `geometry(@parent)`) are supported only from QGIS 3 onwards. Just in case anyone reading this is still using 2.18...